# LG C1 Firmware Flashing/Modifying

Tags: disassemblers, decompile, firmware-analysis, smart-devices

I have a new TV that is smart enough to not have options and configuration I can actually use, and worse of all my tv changes all setting like brightness, sharpness, warmth and input setting to what it wants when it wants, especially wheneve Dolby or HDR setting kick in from an external source or app such as Netflix and it hurts my eyes, I have the brightness set low for a reason.

How would I go about diagnosing or determining what firmware, architecture, OS or such it runs to work it from the inside out, id like to take control of my property.

Comment: I have seen some firmware for LG C1 on the internet, so please select the one that match your TV. You might need to look into the TV's setting section to find out what the exact model code is. Also, is [webOS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebOS) looks similar to the OS in your device? If yes, then from the wiki, your TV is running Linux Kernel on ARM, and there are actually some projects on the net on reversing webOS. Good luck!